# calling 'parent' function from within embedded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page where using jquery I swap out the 'body' content with another page

```
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="TopNavBar">
    <a class="navBtn" link="EmployeeCounts.html" href="javascript:void(0);">Employee Counts</a>
    <a class="navBtn admin" link="EmployeePool.html" href="javascript:void(0);"> Employee Pool</a>
    <a class="navBtn admin" link="Admin.html" href="javascript:void(0);">Admin</a>
</div>

<div id="bodyContent"></div>
```

```
$("#bodyContent").load('EmployeeCounts.html');
```

There is a function in the 'parent' page that I want to reference from the 'embedded' page.  All the code I find online talks about parent/child but the child is a second window that opens separately, not embedded and that code does not seem to be working in my case.

Comment: `but the child is a second window that opens separately`  what do you mean here?,  If your using `$(selector).load()` from jquery, then this won't be another window..

Answer (score 0):

yeah, someone helped me see that it was all about scope.  I had the function in the documentready.  I moved it out of there and the "child" code was able to call the function.